# Why does var behave differently when iterating through PropertyDescriptorCollection?

Tags: c#, var

In the code below, using var in the foreach loop breaks the code. Why is that?

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public Guid Ssn { get; set; }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var foo = new Person {Name = "Foo", Age = 99, Ssn = Guid.NewGuid()};

            PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(foo);

            foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in properties)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(property.Name);//Works
            }

            //foreach (var property in properties)
            //{
            //    Console.WriteLine(property.Name);//Does not work
            //}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does it break? What is the error?

Comment: It throws compile time error: object' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Searching on that literal error would have found a load of questions already on SO.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I think I even saw an exact duplicate last week, also asking about `PropertyDescriptorCollection`, but I can't find it unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PropertyDescriptorCollection` is an old class, which was designed at a time where the generic `IEnumerable<T>` did not exist. As such, it only implements `IEnumerable`, meaning the compiler does not know the type of the contained objects, and `var` resolves to `object`. `PropertyDescriptorCollection` does admittedly provide a custom strongly-typed indexer, but that indexer is never used for `foreach` loops.

Answer (score 1):

PropertyDescriptorCollection doenst implement IEnumerable<T>,
it only Implements IEnumerable. Thats why var defaults to object (Check the tooltip on mouseover of the var keyword).

you could also easily write:

```
 foreach (Foo foo in properties)
 {
 }
```

Which will result in a similar Error (InvalidCastException).

Comment: No, that will result in a different error, that will result in an `InvalidCastException`.